# Return multiple gt tables in function

Tags: r, r-markdown, gt

Is there a way to return multiple gt tables from a user written function within R markdown? Typically, I would combine tables in a list and output them. However when I do so, the html document displays some formatting code instead of the tables.

````
```{r}
library(gt)
df <- data.frame(a=1:5, b=c("a", "c", "a", "c", "c"))

return_multiple <- function(data) {
  tab1 <- df %>% gt()
  tab2 <- df %>% gt()
  
  return(tab1) # only first table printed
  return(tab2)

### does not work ###
#  try <- list(tab1, tab2)
#  return(try) # formatting code printed
}

return_multiple(df)
```
````

This is the output when I return the list (return(try)):

[image]

Comment: notice that both answers below use `results='asis'` in the chunk options. If you add just that, your original approach will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `purrr::walk` for this, e.g.

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r, results='asis'}
library(gt)
df <- data.frame(a=1:5, b=c("a", "c", "a", "c", "c"))

purrr::walk(list(df,df), ~.x |> 
              gt() |> 
              tab_caption("Caption here") |> 
              print())
```
````

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just add `results='asis'` to your original approach:

````
```{r echo=F, results='asis'}
library(gt)
df <- data.frame(a=1:5, b=c("a", "c", "a", "c", "c"))
return_multiple <- function(data) list(gt(data), gt(data))

return_multiple(df)
```
````